# Get JSON array from string AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I get this response from my ajax request. Ajax call function php get_contents() and this is HTML output of reqeusted page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsLoaded = '';

    var searchCategories = [{"title":"something","id":"3","count":28117},{"title":"something","id":"35","count":14647},{"title":"something","id":"1","count":1124},{"title":"something","id":"6","count":836},{"title":"something","id":"5","count":18645},{"title":"something","id":"7","count":4791},{"title":"something","id":"8","count":21117},{"title":"something","id":"76","count":179},{"title":"something","id":"9","count":81435},{"title":"something","id":"13","count":14695},{"title":"something","id":"10","count":1517},{"title":"something","id":"11","count":2544},{"title":"something","id":"14","count":826},{"title":"something","id":"74","count":128},{"title":"something","id":"12","count":835},{"title":"something","id":"79","count":785},{"title":"something","id":"57","count":1165},{"title":"something","id":"15","count":2160},{"title":"something","id":"16","count":5649},{"title":"something","id":"72","count":2521},{"title":"something","id":"17","count":518},{"title":"something","id":"55","count":5535},{"title":"something","id":"18","count":6712},{"title":"something","id":"19","count":710},{"title":"something","id":"32","count":363},{"title":"something","id":"80","count":1102},{"title":"something","id":"20","count":1585},{"title":"something","id":"21","count":16502},{"title":"something","id":"36","count":221},{"title":"something","id":"101","count":65},{"title":"something","id":"25","count":5644},{"title":"something","id":"111","count":208},{"title":"something","id":"26","count":1019},{"title":"something","id":"27","count":9061},{"title":"something","id":"29","count":8211},{"title":"something","id":"78","count":874},{"title":"something","id":"22","count":11956},{"title":"something","id":"28","count":2873},{"title":"something","id":"2","count":3223},{"title":"something","id":"24","count":3723},{"title":"something","id":"41","count":3989},{"title":"something","id":"53","count":1131},{"title":"something","id":"30","count":26333},{"title":"something","id":"31","count":4672},{"title":"something","id":"42","count":313},{"title":"something","id":"67","count":2182},{"title":"something","id":"75","count":164},{"title":"something","id":"83","count":1822},{"title":"something","id":"59","count":3242},{"title":"something","id":"69","count":994},{"title":"something","id":"33","count":2786},{"title":"something","id":"37","count":20823},{"title":"something","id":"65","count":5742},{"title":"something","id":"23","count":6346},{"title":"something","id":"81","count":711},{"title":"something","id":"43","count":1399},{"title":"something","id":"61","count":8359}];        var durationDetails = [{"count":25237,"name":"short"},{"count":75812,"name":"medium"},{"count":27213,"name":"long"},{"count":128262,"name":"all"}];

</script>
```

together with some other HTML. I need to parste only the JSON string. I have tried :contains and .find() but without success. Could you guys pleas tell me what should I do?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Which is the json string? would be nice if you properly formatted that array.

Comment: Do you mean you get HTML back with a script in it. And in that script tag you have a json?

Comment: BTW that is not even a json...

Comment: This is whole just plain text. which I get from php get_contents(). it's HTML copy of the page, which I get from ajax response.

Comment: OK, what you are getting back is just HTML.   But it sounds like you are just wanting to get the json (which I am assuming is what you are showing in the searchCategories.   If this is correct then you should modify your php to only return the json array portion and not the other script tags, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax success callback add

```
success: function (r) {
    $(r).filter('script').appendTo('head');
    gotTheStuff();
}
```

Then you can simply use the variables

```
function gotTheStuff(){
    console.log(searchCategories);
    // do stuff with the array
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5y6umbL/2/

---

Alternatively

```
success: function (r) {
    $.globalEval($(r).filter('script').text());
    gotTheStuff();
}
```